# Phoenix Elixir Distillery not using correct database connection

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, distillery

I'm trying to build a Phoenix application with Distillery, however when I try start the compiled application I keep getting an error about not being able to fine the database.

```
17:44:50.925 [error] GenServer #PID<0.1276.0> terminating
** (KeyError) key :database not found in: [hostname: "localhost", username: "martinffx", types: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.TypeModule, port: 5432, name: Glitchr.Repo.Pool, otp_app: :glitchr, repo: Glitchr.Repo, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, pool_size: 10, ssl: true, pool_timeout: 5000, timeout: 15000, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, pool_size: 10, ssl: true, pool: DBConnection.Poolboy]
    (elixir) lib/keyword.ex:343: Keyword.fetch!/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:76: Postgrex.Protocol.connect/1
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:134: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
```

Now the details above aren't what I've provided in the `prod.ex`

```
config :glitchr, Glitchr.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [host: "localhost", port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  server: true,
  root: ".",
  version: Mix.Project.config[:version],
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE")

config :glitchr, Glitchr.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  url: System.get_env("DATABASE_URL"),
  pool_size: String.to_integer(System.get_env("POOL_SIZE") || "10"),
  ssl: true
```

Where my database url is `DATABASE_URL=postgres://glitchr:password@db:5433/glitchr`

Why is that? How can I debug what I'm not getting right?

Comment: I don't think `System.get_env` will work in config since they'll be evaluated at compile time, not run time. See https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/runtime-configuration.html.

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert! Always helping with my Elixir journey! Replacing `System.get_env` with `{:system ""}` works.

Comment: I have an identical error when I'm deploying to Heroku, but it's not being solved by using `{:system, "DATABASE_URL"}` etc. Did changing to this really solve it?